# Node JS Http.get file from aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, http, download

I'm attempting to download a PDF document from any of the 'download' buttons on [this](http://www2.nationalgrid.com/UK/Industry-information/System-charges/Electricity-transmission/Assistance-for-areas-with-high-distribution-costs/) website using Node's Http module. How can I download the PDF document without downloading the aspx file instead, which is what is happening with my code? For some reason, my code downloads an aspx file that says 'Error Message - File does not exist or you do not have permission to view this file', even though I can easily download the file from my web browser. Here is my code:

```js
var pdf_text = require("pdf-text");
var request = require("request");
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var urllib = require("url");

var path = "final.pdf";
var url = "http://www2.nationalgrid.com/UK/Industry-information/System-charges/Electricity-transmission/Assistance-for-areas-with-high-distribution-costs/";
var links = [];

request(url, function(error, response, html) {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                $(".txtLnk").each(function() {
                        links.push("http://www2.nationalgrid.com" + $(this).attr("href"));
                });

                var file = fs.createWriteStream(urllib.parse(links[1]).pathname.split('/').pop());
                var options = {
                        host: urllib.parse(links[1]).host,
                        port: 80,
                        path: urllib.parse(links[1]).pathname,
                        headers: {
                                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:43.0) Gecko/201001101 Firefox/43.0"
                        }
                };

                http.get(options, function(res) {
                        res.on('data', function(data) {
                                file.write(data);
                        }).on('end', function() {
                                file.end();
                        });
                });

                console.log(links);
        }
});

function data_from_pdf(pdf) {
        pdf_text("pdf/" + pdf, function(err, chunks) {
                var data = chunks.join("").substring(chunks.join("").search("(p/kWh)") + 6, chunks.join("").search("(p/kWh)") + 21);
                var date = data.substring(0, data.indexOf("/") + 3);
                var rate = data.substring(data.indexOf("/") + 3);
                var json_data = "{" + "\n\tname: " + "final.pdf" + ",\n\tdate: " + date + ",\n\trate: " + rate + "\n}";

                return json_data;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, if I just replace "options" with the base URL, it works. Strange. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

var path = "./final.pdf";
var url = "http://www2.nationalgrid.com/UK/Industry-information/System-charges/Electricity-transmission/Assistance-for-areas-with-high-distribution-costs/";
var links = [];

request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            $(".txtLnk").each(function() {
                    links.push("http://www2.nationalgrid.com" + $(this).attr("href"));
            });

            var r = request(links[0]);
            r.on('response', function (res) {
                    console.log(res.headers);
                    res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
            });
    }
});
```